# WORDPRESS: How to add a start rating in testimonials?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a casa theme (wordpress) and It has a native testimonials but it doesn't have a star rating. It's possible to add star rating, just a plugin for that?

Comment: do you need rating plugin 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/rating-widget/
https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/best-rating-review-plugins-wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugins https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-testimonials/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/testimonial-rotator/screenshots/ are providing testimonial with rating features. both are very good in results i personally used that.